# Simple HTTP Server C code doesn't work on my Mac OS X

Tags: c, macos, http, tcp

I am trying to implement a very simple HTTP server C code, and while doing that I search this on the web :
https://medium.com/from-the-scratch/http-server-what-do-you-need-to-know-to-build-a-simple-http-server-from-scratch-d1ef8945e4fa

And I copy-and-paste the code which is shown below.(also the code in the link up there)

And I build it and run it on my MacBook, 
and it runs on my computer, so I typed "localhost:8080" on Safari.

And I have this result only.

**Safari Can't Connect to the Server
Safari can't open the page "localhost:8080" because Safari can't connect to the server "localhost".**

I have no idea why this is not working. According to that site, It should work, so I am now frustrated.

Anyone please help me?

```c
// Server side C program to demonstrate HTTP Server programming
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PORT 8080
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int server_fd, new_socket; long valread;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int addrlen = sizeof(address);

    // Only this line has been changed. Everything is same.
    char *hello = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/plain\nContent-Length: 12\n\nHello world!";

    // Creating socket file descriptor
    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0)
    {
        perror("In socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons( PORT );

    memset(address.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof address.sin_zero);


    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address))<0)
    {
        perror("In bind");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (listen(server_fd, 10) < 0)
    {
        perror("In listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while(1)
    {
        printf("\n+++++++ Waiting for new connection ++++++++\n\n");
        if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0)
        {
            perror("In accept");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        char buffer[30000] = {0};
        valread = read( new_socket , buffer, 30000);
        printf("%s\n",buffer );
        write(new_socket , hello , strlen(hello));
        printf("------------------Hello message sent-------------------");
        close(new_socket);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It works just fine on my Mac.  You might be having a firewall problem.

Comment: Your link is garbage, and there is no such thing as a 'simple HTTP server'. You need a good knowledge of RFC 2616 and successors to implement HTTP, and you also need to know that it is all based on the Telnet line definition, in which lines are terminated by `\r\n`, not `\n`, which the author of your link doesn't appear to know.

Comment: Most likely you have a network problem.

Comment: @SteveSummit really? I should check "firewall problem". Can you tell me what is it btw?

Comment: Go to System Preferences, the Security & Privacy dialog, the Firewall tab.  Turning off the firewall might help.  (But remember to turn it back on when you're done playing.)

Comment: @SteveSummit I checked it but by Firewall is set "off" at the very beginning... :( what would be the problem then..?

Comment: I don't know.  Another thing to try would be connecting to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` instead of localhost.  Another thing that sometimes makes a difference (although I wouldn't expect it to in this case) is whether you have an active network connection.  (No, you shouldn't need a network connection to connect to your own machine, but I've had problems with this.)

Comment: Also, per the comment from @user207421 , definitely change all `\n`'s in your `hello` string to `\r\n`.

Comment: You can check against `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` (typed in terminal of course) which should work out of the box on MacOS to potentially narrow down the domain of your problem.

Comment: OT: regarding: `char *hello = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/plain\nContent-Length: 12\n\nHello world!";` 1) for ease of readability, honor the right hand margin (usually at column 72 or 80)  2) use the correct line breaks "\r\n" not '\n', including the last line.  Suggest: `char *hello = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" newline "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n" newline "Content-Length: 12\r\n\r\n" newline "Hello world!\r\n";`